# Generate property stub showing instead of generate method stub

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am defining a new method without definition and expecting Microsoft Visual Studio to generate '`method stub` for me i.e.,

```
book.NameChanged += (OnNameChanged);
book.NameChanged += (OnNameChanged1);
```

When I put my cursor on `OnNameChanged`and hold down `control + .` keys, I am expecting MS Visual Studio to generate a method stub but MS Visual Studio is only giving me options to generate either a field stub or a property stub. I have come across such situation multiple times when I want MS Visual Studio to generate a method for me but it only gives me options to rather generate a field or a property. Can someone explain what is going on.

Comment: What do you need those brackets for? get rid of them and VS gives you "generate method stub" option.

Comment: @Bahman_Aries Yes I figured that out somehow. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove parenthesis in `book.NameChanged += (OnNameChanged)` and MS Visual Studio will generate the method stub i.e.,

From: 
    book.NameChanged += (OnNameChanged);

To: 
    book.NameChanged += OnNameChanged;